# Set array items in react js state

Tags: reactjs

Here I have a state which its initial value is an empty obj.

```
const [error, setError] = useState({});
```

In the next step, I'm checking if there is vacant input, set its key to the error state :

```
if (emptyInputs.length) {
            emptyInputs.forEach(key => setError({ ...error, [key]: true }));
```

but only one of the empty inputs name sets to my error state:

[image]

is there anyone face to this problem?

Comment: First don't provide the code snippet as image, instead provide them as real code snippet. Next provide the data that you receive from `emptyInputs` ..

Comment: Here you are. I changed my answer

Comment: Could you provide a emptyInputs data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are looping through the emptyInput for each item you are assigning a new object to the error state because of that you are losing the previous state/key, first of all, you will have to copy the previous object to keep its values and then assign a new key like so.

This is a recommended way to set the state if your state depends on the previous state.

```
emptyInputs.forEach(key => setError(prevState => ({...prevState, [key]: true})))
```

This is not a recommended way to update the state like this because this way doesn't guarantee getting the latest state for each update if your state changes very frequently.

```
emptyInputs.forEach(key => setError({...error, [key]: true}))
```